# Log4j2 on Ant Web Project

Tags: java, ant, log4j2

I´m developing a Web Application, using Glassfish, and I´m migrating from log4J to log4J2.

**FIRST QUESTION:**

I´m  using this log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
<Properties>
<Property name="log-path">mypath</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
<RollingFile name="file-log" fileName="${log-path}/mylog.log"
filePattern="${log-path}/mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
<PatternLayout>
<pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
<Policies>
<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
</Policies>
</RollingFile>

<Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
<PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
</Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
<Root level="info" additivity="false">
<appender-ref ref="console"/>
</Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Where do I put this information. In src, in a package? I don t know where to put it, because my app do not recognize it.

**SECOND QUESTION**:

If i want to introduce the information of logged user and sessionId, can I put this in my xml file?

**THIRD QUESTION**:
If I put this on my code:

log.info("message"), what´s the prupose to have a root level? It´s not me that determine which level is on my log, on different messages?